# concatenating strings for each character in a string using functions

Tags: python, morse-code

Basically I am writing a morse code program with functions and I am having trouble getting the next letter in the string to convert to morse. So how do I concatenate each character of the string and then print it. I believe I am having trouble on how to work the for loop for each character in the string because it just stops on the last character.

```
def encodeChartoMorse(text_input):
  all_caps=text_input.upper()
  length=len(all_caps)
  string=''
  for letter in range(0, length):
    char = all_caps[letter]
    

    if (char == "A"):
      return (".-")
    elif (char == "B"):
      return("-...")
    elif (char== "C"):
      return("-.-.")
    elif (char == "D"):
      return("-..")
    elif (char == "E"):
      return(".")
    elif (char == "F"):
      return("..-.")
    elif (char == "G"):
      return("--.")
    elif (char == "H"):
      return("....")
    elif (char == "I"):
      return("..")
    elif (char == "J"):
      return(".---")
    elif (char == "K"):
      return("-.-")
    elif (char == "L"):
      return(".-..")
    elif (char == "M"):
      return("--")
    elif (char == "N"):
      return("-.")
    elif (char == "O"):
      return("---")
    elif (char == "P"):
      return(".--.")
    elif (char == "Q"):
      return(" --.-")
    elif (char == "R"):
      return(".-.")
    elif (char == "S"):
      return("...")
    elif (char == "T"):
      return("-")
    elif (char == "U"):
      return("..-")
    elif (char == "V"):
      return("...-")
    elif (char == "W"):
      return(".--")
    elif (char == "X"):
      return("-..-")
    elif (char == "Y"):
      return("-.--")
    elif (char == "Z"):
      return("--..")
    else:
      return('*')
  string=string+char
  return char
   
def main():
  
  text_input=str(input("Enter some text to convert to Morse code: "))
  print(text_input)
 
  morse_code=encodeChartoMorse(text_input)
  print(morse_code)
 

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are returning in each conditional. Instead of `return (".-")` for the condition `char == "A"`, you should have `char = ".-"`. Then your string concatenation of `string = string + char` will work as expected.

The way it is working now the function `encodeChartoMorse` finds one match and then returns from the function completely. This is why you were only matching the first letter.

Comment: Good answer. Just to add onto your explanation, `return` you can think of as a line which stops going through the function, so once you call return, all lines after that in the current function will not be run.

Comment: how would I reverse the output

Comment: @wiskah That sounds like a separate question, and one you can probably find an answer to by searching here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting the Morse code in a dictionary so it would be more efficient and easier to code. Then loop through the input and concatenate the dictionary value to the string.